# how to send text to a process in a shell script?

Tags: shell, unix

So I have a Linux program that runs in a while(true) loop, which waits for user input, process it and print result to stdout.

I want to write a shell script that open this program, feed it lines from a txt file, one line at a time and save the program output for each line to a file.

So I want to know if there is any command for:
    - open a program
  - send text to a process
  - receive output from that program

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
cat file | while read line; do
    answer=$(echo "$line" | prog)
done
```

This will run a new instance of `prog` for each line.  The line will be the standard input of `prog` and the output will be put in the variable `answer` for your script to further process.

Some people object to the "cat file |" as this creates a process where you don't really need one.  You can also use file redirection by putting it after the `done`:

```
while read line; do
    answer=$(echo "$line" | prog)
done < file
```

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain what he or she finds incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [pipes and redirections](http://www.injunea.demon.co.uk/pages/page208.htm) ? You can use pipes to feed input from one program into another. You can use redirection to send contents of files to programs, and/or write output to files.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want a script written in bash.

1. To open a file you just need to type a name of it.
2. To send a text to a program you either pass it through `|` or with `<` (take input from file)
3. To receive output you use `>` to redirect output to some file or `>>` to redirect as well but append the results instead of truncating the file

To achieve what you want in bash, you could write:

```
#/bin/bash

cat input_file | xargs -l1 -i{} your_program {} >> output_file
```

This calls `your_program` for each line from `input_file` and appends results to `output_file`